# Cloning Windows 8.1 to 30 identical machines; what should I use so they will activate properly?

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, usb, clone

I have 30 client computers. These are Windows 8.1 tablet style i5 machines. They all have OEM Windows 8.1 Pro. I have a volume MBL.

I want to make identical copies of the original machine, all drivers and applications just as they are. No OOBE nor generalizing is needed. Should I be using MDT and ADK? What are the steps to get an exact clone of a machine in MDT?

These machines all have identical hardware. I just need to have different SID's so they will activate. I dont want to have to touch them at all except to change the boot order and plugging in the network cable.

Next problem is that they have no PXE or any drives of any kind. Can I deploy a clone WIM via a USB drive? There is only one usb port and hard drives are not removable.

Comment: It sounds like you need to still just run `sysprep /generalize` but make a [answer file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824849.aspx)

Comment: No PXE? So changing the boot order there is no option to boot to network?

Answer (score 0):

If you build a WinPE environment via ADK (or just use MDT to build the Generic_x86.iso), you can put that on a memory stick and then capture and deploy a WIM from the stick itself using DISM.

I use this technique on tablets that have a single USB port (and no wired ethernet ports) or for reimaging in the field/at conferences.